# How to provide value in criteria expression for the 'Raw' datatype field of Oracle in C#.net

Tags: c#, oracle

I am trying to delete one record from oracle table in C#.net.
but i am getting the following error message.

**"ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got BINARY"**

Following is my table defination:

```
CREATE Table Study
(   
    UID RAW (16) DEFAULT SYS_GUID() NOT NULL ,
    Notification VARCHAR2 (5) NOT NULL
);
```

I am writing the delete query like: `DELETE FROM Study WHERE UID = MyByteArry`

Here `MyByteArry` is the value of `UID` field from Study table read before executing the delete query.

See if the field data type is varchar then normally we provide the value in criteria expression as:

```
DELETE FROM Study WHERE UID = 'Some Value'
```

But how can i specify value in criteria expression for field which having a Raw data type.

Following is the C# code:

```
private void ProcessItem(DataRow thisDataRow)
{
    ArrayList cmdParams = new ArrayList();
    string strSQL = "";

    strSQL = @"DELETE FROM Study
    WHERE UID = :paramUID";

    cmdParams.Add(thisDataRow["UID"]);
    objDbCommExt.ExecuteNonQuery(strSQL, cmdParams);
}

public int ExecuteNonQuery(string strSQL, ArrayList cmdParams = null)
{
    IDbCommand objIDbCommand = GetCommand();
    objIDbCommand.CommandText = strSQL;
    if (cmdParams != null)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < cmdParams.Count; i++)
        {
            IDataParameter objIDataParameter = GetDataParameter(_commandChar + "param" +
            i.ToString(), cmdParams[i]);
            objIDbCommand.Parameters.Add(objIDataParameter);
        }
    }
    return ExecuteNonQuery(objIDbCommand);
}

public int ExecuteNonQuery(IDbCommand objIDbCommand)
{
    objIDbCommand.Connection = _connection;
    return objIDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
}

public IDataParameter GetDataParameter(string parameterName = "", object parameterValue = null)
{
IDbCommand objIDbCommand = new OracleCommand();
IDataParameter parameter = objIDbCommand.CreateParameter();
parameter.ParameterName = parameterName;
parameter.Value = parameterValue;
return parameter;
}
```

Comment: I'm still missing the code for GetDataParameter.

Comment: GetDataParameter added.

Comment: Try: `cmdParams.Add(thisDataRow["UID"].ToString());`

Comment: Tried it without success! getting the error of "ORA-01722: invalid number"

Comment: The issue may be that [UID](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/uid.php) is one of Oracle keywords, try to rename column, lets say U_ID.

Comment: Thanks a lot yar. Problem is resolved. UID is keyword in Oracle and it should be enclosed in double quote when using it in SQL queries.

Comment: Yes. But I strongly recommend renaming that column. Naming column like "UID", "USER" is dangerous, you can update or delete all rows unintentionally.